# Sending email using Java GUI: Not working

Tags: java, email

I am writing this code but it is not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String to = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Email is to be sent to");
    String from = "raedafd@gmail.com";
    String host = "localhost";
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Subject"));
        message.setContent(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Content:"), "text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the following error is appearing:

```
 Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException
```

Comment: I don't see port 25 being explicitly set anywhere, and it it be the default, then you might not want to use it anyway.  Please refer this good [Mkyong tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) for a working example of how to connect to GMail via Java.

Comment: Does it work from an app. with no GUI? If not, this has nothing to do with Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way the email API expects you to have a SMTP server running on localhost (your own PC), did you setup and start an email server?

If you want to send an email from your gmail account check this example: https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/